# Can a graphics card speed up Gazebo?

Tags: gazebo-1.9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am running Gazebo on a laptop which is geared with 2 graphics cards, one Intel (low spec and low power consumption) for one nVidia (more powerful).

I do not see any performance gap between the two, and neither between the nVidia closed source driver and the open source one (Nouveau, shipped with Ubuntu 13.04).

So I wonder if a graphics cards can improve the performance of Gazebo and how. It looks like all processes are supported by the CPU (around 60% - 70% of use for the 4 cores).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4191/can-a-graphics-card-speed-up-gazebo?/) by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 316 on 2013-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I answer to my own question after further trials.

So:

- Intel chip with the default Ubuntu driver for it: simulation runs OK, but the whole system becomes slow
- NVIDIA chip with the Nouveau Gallium driver and the BIOS option "OS detection for NVIDIA Optimus" enabled, simulation runs OK, the system is somehow faster
- NVIDIA chip with the Nouveau Gallium driver without the BIOS option "OS detection for NVIDIA Optimus" disabled, simulation crashes, error message "X Error of failed request: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter)"
- NVIDIA chip and driver, simulation OK and system fast

So the NVIDIA driver is clearly the best option, even the Intel chip is far easier to setup for a good result.

PS: for reference, I use a LENOVO T420 laptop.

---

Originally posted by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) with karma: 316 on 2013-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3